# How to replace existing ms access database with c# code?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

```
String baseDirectory = @"F:\Backup";
String mdbSourceFilePath = @"D:\Db\abc.mdb";
String mdbTargetFileName = "abc.mdb";

String fullDirectory = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd"));

if (!Directory.Exists(baseDirectory))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(baseDirectory);

if (!Directory.Exists(fullDirectory))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(fullDirectory);

String mdbTargetFilePath = Path.Combine(fullDirectory, mdbTargetFileName);
File.Copy(mdbSourceFilePath, mdbTargetFilePath);
```

This is for backup of database. If I click on backup button this is creating backup database but if I click it again is is not overwriting existing database. I want to replace the existing database.

Comment: [rtm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), there is an overload that can be configured to overwrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a third (optional) argument to `File.Copy` called `overwrite`. Set it to `true` to overwrite an existing file, as long as it isn't read-only:

```
File.Copy(mdbSourceFilePath, mdbTargetFilePath, overwrite: true);
```

An alternative would be to check if `mdbTargetFilePath` exists and delete it prior to the copy:

```
if (File.Exists(mdbTargetFilePath))
{
    File.Delete(mdbTargetFilePath);
}
```

Comment: Not working ... as in ...? Do you have delete permission in the folder? Can you delete it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking whether that file exists or not using
`if (File.Exists(fileName))`
then you can use 
`File.Replace` method